# I don't have navigation bar in the beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, navigation, mini-frames

I saw many threads that want to remove the navigation bar but my problem is I don't have a navigation bar...nor do I have page numbers.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{grffile}
    \usetheme{Frankfurt}

    \begin{document}

    \title{}
    \author{}
    \date{\today}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
```

Comment: The reasons are several: 1) the document does not compile (the `\end{document}` is missing), 2a) you selected a bad theme as Frankfurt does not provide page numbering (see the [Beamer Theme Matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/)) unless you don't insert it by yourself, 2b) as you didn't split the document in sections there's no need to navigate, so nothing appears. Add some other frames with some sections and subsection: you will be able to navigate. :)